# Find all functions such that there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$, for all $i\in \mathbb{Z}$, $f(i+n)=f(i)+n$

Tags: functions

I have found one such function is $f_n(x)=x+n$.
Are there any other functions that satisfy the condition?

Comment: where is this funtion defined ?

Comment: These are the periodic functions, they are characterized by their period (which in this case is $n$) along with the tuple $(f(0),\dots f(n-1))$. Any possible period and tuple gives you a function of this form.

Comment: Set of all integers.

Comment: You mean $\exists n \in \mathbb{N} \forall i \in \mathbb{Z} f(i+n)=f(i)+n$, right?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Jorge As currently written, such an $f$ cannot be periodic unless you allow $n=0$.  I would agree that every such function decomposes as an $n$-periodic function and a particular monotonic function, though (hint to OP)

Comment: Oh yeah I made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those instances when finding one function can help us simplify the condition to find all such functions.

For instance, you found $f_n(x)=x+n$ works.  Let's suppose $f(x)$ is another such function.  What can we say about $g(x) = f(x) - f_n(x)$?  Well,

$$g(i+n) = f(i+n) - f_n(i+n) = (f(i)+n) - (f_n(i)+n) = f(i) - f_n(i) = g(i)$$

Since this is true for every $i$, this means $g$ has period $n$, and since this is the only condition on $g$, any function with period $n$ works.  Choose *any* of them to be your $g$.

Then just solve for $f$:  $$f(x) = g(x) + f_n(x) = g(x) + x + n$$

Comment: Thats nice.....